# Auto-collapse nestled list using jQuery & Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is creating a method that (on clicking a element) collapse all other elements within the nestled list that are not the target element or associated parent containers. I have looked around but nothing works for my list.

Basically I'm trying to collapse all active list elements except the target one.

- Using bootstrap to handle a lot of things.
- I have a method that makes a list element active on click.
- The alert seems to output the ids of elements that need to be affected, and nothing collapses. Suggestions?

List Structure:

```
 - Building
  - Floor
    - Room
```

Code:

```js
//JS - Attempt to collapse all elements not clicked:

$('.expandable-menu a').click(function(e) {
    var parent = $("#" + e.target.id).attr('data-parent');
    $(".expandable-menu a").each(function() {
        //if 1. has class active 2.Not target event,  3.Not a parent of target 
        if ($(this).hasClass('active') && $(this).attr('id') !== (e.target.id) && $(this).attr('id') !== (parent)) {
            // alert($(this).attr('id') );
            $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('collapsed');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!--HTML - Example chunk from list:-->

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li id="level1">
        <a id="title-b0" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#title-loc" data-target="#content-b0" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span>
            Biology
        </a>
        
        <ul id="content-b0" class="nav collapse" style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false">
            <li id="level2">
                <a id="title-b0f0" class="" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="title-b0" data-target="#content-f0" aria-expanded="true">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span> 
                    Floor 4 
                </a>
                
                <ul id="content-f0" class="nav collapse in" style="" aria-expanded="true"></ul>
                <a id="title-b0f1" class="" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="title-b0" data-target="#content-f1" aria-expanded="true">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
                    Floor 3
                </a>
                
                <ul id="content-f1" class="nav collapse in" style="" aria-expanded="true">
                    <li>
                        <a id="room-select" href="#">    
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>
                            Room 112
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There are lots of solutions for this, check [this one](http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/collapsible-lists/) out.

Comment: If you're going to go to the trouble of writing a code snippet, at least make it sort of work. Click the "Run" button in your post and have a look, there are multiple things wrong (for starters, no element has class `expandable-menu`, and second up is the invalid HTML which causes the hjavascript to end up in the markup)

Comment: @ Jamiec soz code nippet was added by moderator edit...html chunk was only there as html example

Comment: @Orbitall - yeah I can see that now, sorry. In which case they did you a disservice by changing your posted code into a bad code snippet.

Comment: I edited the code trying to make it work again. I hope it's better now

Comment: Cheers, now snipet is working... I will explain like below that once fully opened to floor 3 I  will need it to close(auto collapse) once floor 4 is opened(even tho its empty) and for other 2nd level items if added. same as Biology would collapse if other level 1 elements where added and clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

This example may help you out

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tree li').each(function() {
        if ($(this).children('ul').length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('parent');
        }
    });

    $('.tree li.parent > a').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
        $(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
    });

    $('#all').click(function() {

        $('.tree li').each(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
        });
    });

    $('.tree li').each(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
    });

});
```

```css
a{
 cursor:pointer;
}
.tree ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
.tree li a {
    line-height: 25px;
}
.tree > ul > li > a {
    color: #3B4C56;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tree li.parent > a {
    padding: 0 0 0 28px;
}
.tree li.parent > a:before {
    background-position: 25px center;
    content: "-"; 
    display: block;
    height: 21px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 23px;
}
.tree ul li.active > a:before {
    background-position: 0 center;
}
.tree ul li ul {
    border-left: 1px solid #D9DADB;
    display: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 0 25px;
}
.tree ul li ul li {
    position: relative;
}
.tree ul li ul li:before {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #E2E2E3;
   
    left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    width: 15px;
}
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="tree">
<button id="all">Toggle All</button>
  
<ul>
  <li><a>First Level</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
    <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
    <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>First Level</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a>Second Level</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a>Third Level</a></li>
      <li><a>Third Level</a></li>
      <li><a>Third Level</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a>Fourth Level</a></li>
        <li><a>Fourth Level</a></li>
        <li><a>Fourth Level</a>
         <ul>
          <li><a>Fifth Level</a></li>
          <li><a>Fifth Level</a></li>
          <li><a>Fifth Level</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>First Level</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
    <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although this method works nicely, trying not to rewrite all the bootstrap compatible collapse and redo my active method, was hoping there was an easy method of collapsing using bootstrap backend...

Comment: Plus I have done this already, I need to implement the collapse of other elements on same level, so if I selected another First Level it would collapse the Active ones.